# Infinite loop when using wicket-guice

Tags: java, wicket, guice

im using wicket since a couple of months now and i started to evluate wicket-guice recently. 
So im quite a guice noobie :)

Every page got a ServiceClass (lets call it DoService) which manages a number of Objects (i.e. User) ...
Those objects also got an reference to that ServiceClass for some reasons.

```
public class page ... {
  @Inject
  private DoService doService;
}

public class DoService ... {
  private Collection<User> ... 
}

public class User {
   @Inject
   private DoService doService;
}
```

Im not quite sure, but i think the following exception occurs cause of the circular references of dependencies though i thought guice manages this all by itsself.

Whatever.....if you need more information to understand my problem pls ask :)

Thanks in advance

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
     at java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.<init>(InvocationTargetException.java:54)
     at WICKET_....DoService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$ce256f9.invoke(<generated>)
     at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
     at org.apache.wicket.proxy.LazyInitProxyFactory$CGLibInterceptor.intercept(LazyInitProxyFactory.java:317)
     at WICKET_....DoService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d1f8934e.rollback(<generated>)
     at WICKET_c....DoService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$ce256f9.invoke(<generated>)
     at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
......
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your design is incorrect: a domain object should not contain references to services. You indeed have a circular dependency.

Comment: Hi, i agree with u though this is not about DO design, i just wanted to provide an easy example. In the real world Application the back reference is important :(

Comment: If the back reference is important, it might not be a bad idea to reconsider the design. Would be nice to see the design as you see it so other people can also review it.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your reply. After some further investigations it showed up that the error was caused by a whole different problem. The lifecycle of the Service was managed by a different object since i needed it to be scoped as threadlocal. Due to the fact wicket-guice is working with proxy-objects those proxies were attached to the threadlocal and the next time this dependency was injected, a proxy of this proxy was created by wicket-guice. That led to the infinit loop :(

Answer (score 0):

What Guice does here is to create a new User instance for every DoService instance and a new DoService instance for every User instance. I don't think that's what you want to archive here (apart from the questionable design).
There are several ways around this issue:

1. Use appropriate Providers in your module
2. Use singleton scope in guice
3. Use guice only for one of these instanciations. Have one object create the other and supply itself to the other's constructor for back-reference.